# Decrypting AES CTR Little Endian with PHP

Tags: php, cryptography, aes, mcrypt, commoncrypto

I'm having trouble using PHP to decrypt strings that were encrypted with iOS 5.x's CommonCrypto libraries.  Here are the parameters:

```
Algorithm: AES-128
Mode: CTR
Mode options: CTR Little-Endian
Padding: None
```

Here's a sample of my best attempt at it:

```
<?php
$encrypted = base64_decode('MlNFlnXE1sqIsmKZRtjChBvUMgiJlXgdjHVxQJ6JK24Id4uaN9NK/nBtY+cgrMJR/PRJRCmIUx0boQO5XqJYZ8VJ0w==');
$key = base64_decode('HB+dD1Irj2rXQ/nO+IuqSiK9xVE3PD9cZGIGzrMtwtA=');
$iv = base64_decode('2gxxKYU/G4lj7174e5wj+g==');

$cryptor = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'ctr', '');
mcrypt_generic_init($cryptor, $key, $iv);
echo mdecrypt_generic($cryptor, $encrypted);

mcrypt_generic_deinit($cryptor);
mcrypt_module_close($cryptor);
```

The output looks like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolo?N??]ѕȢ?+?
                                             ????x??k????}??'???Ŧ??;t
```

But it should be "**Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do...**" (trailing ellipsis included.)

The block size is 16, and it's getting the first 16 characters right.  This seems to point to a mismatch in the AES CTR counter-incrementing process between Mcrypt and CommonCrypto.  Everybody I've heard from so far has suggested it's an issue of Big Endian vs. Little Endian.

I've spent days trying to figure out all this endianness and counter-incrementing stuff on my own, but it's still voodoo to me.  :-(  I just need some PHP code that properly decrypts my string.  I don't care how fast the algorithm works.  I'm open to ditching Mcrypt in favor of a PHP-native solution or some other PHP extension, as long as it's a common one.  However, changing things on the iOS side is *not* an option.

Please help!

Comment: What is the size of returned by mencrypt_enc_get_iv_size() ?  That should be the length used in oth cases; http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-enc-get-iv-size.php

Comment: It returns 16, same length as my IV.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Block cipher modes are really simple, you can just implement them yourself if two implementations aren't compatible.

Here is a CTR implementation for your particular case:

```
function ctr_crypt($str, $key, $iv) {
    $numOfBlocks = ceil(strlen($str) / 16);

    $ctrStr = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $numOfBlocks; ++$i) {
        $ctrStr .= $iv;

        // increment IV
        for ($j = 0; $j < 16; ++$j) {
            $n = ord($iv[$j]);
            if (++$n == 0x100) {
                // overflow, set this one to 0, increment next
                $iv[$j] = "\0";
            } else {
                // no overflow, just write incremented number back and abort
                $iv[$j] = chr($n);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return $str ^ mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $ctrStr, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
}
```

The algorithm is very simple: You always append and increment the IV until you have a string that is longer (or of equal length) as the input string. Then you encrypt this string using ECB mode and XOR it with the input string.

The incrementation is the complicated part here, because we are dealing with a number in binary. Little Endian means we increment from left to right (j = 0, j < 16, j++). Big Endian would mean that we increment from right to left (j = 15, j >= 0, j--).

Try it out:

```
$encrypted = base64_decode('MlNFlnXE1sqIsmKZRtjChBvUMgiJlXgdjHVxQJ6JK24Id4uaN9NK/nBtY+cgrMJR/PRJRCmIUx0boQO5XqJYZ8VJ0w==');
$key = base64_decode('HB+dD1Irj2rXQ/nO+IuqSiK9xVE3PD9cZGIGzrMtwtA=');
$iv = base64_decode('2gxxKYU/G4lj7174e5wj+g==');

var_dump(ctr_crypt($encrypted, $key, $iv));
// string(67) "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do..."
```

Note: `ctr_crypt` works both as an encryption and as a decryption function.

Comment: + Nice ... but don't you think you should advice against `ECB` ?

Comment: @Baba This implements a CTR encryption mode. ECB is only used in the implementation of it ;)

Comment: i was not referring to the to the CTR implementation but ECB in general ... He might sill be safe if key & IV is not reused but iOS 5.x's CommonCrypto still has better alternatives ... but i guess the question was all about `Decrypting AES CTR Little Endian` ... nice one anyway :)

Comment: Well, look at that.  NikiC, your counter incrementing is "right", and your function works with shorter string+IV combinations that don't trigger the byte overflow.  But with those that do, the results end up not being compatible with CommonCrypto.  It appears CommonCrypto doesn't handle overflow properly, and only ever increments `$iv[0]`, since it worked when I modified your function to do it that way.  Weird.  Anyway, you still deserve the bounty NikiC.  Thanks again!

Comment: @curtisdf That sounds very odd. If they really only increment the first character, then the used xor key would repeat after 16*256 characters (thus any longer cipher would be trivially breakable using frequency analysis). Could you try encrypting a long string (like 100000 characters) of only As and dump the resulting cipher (in hex/base64) somewhere?

Comment: Okay here it is: http://pastebin.com/vRqpjCdN A string of 10,000 "A" characters encrypted using iOS 5's CommonCrypto, same settings as in my original question above.

Comment: Actually, it *is* 100,000 like you asked for.  I misstated the actual length.  Sorry about that.

Comment: @curtisdf Thanks, looks like the key really does repeat after 4096 bytes. Could you please also post the code you used to generate this?

Comment: The code came from an old version of Rob Napier's RNCryptor (http://bit.ly/12U7a8S).  Here's a paste of the essential part of the code I extracted: http://pastebin.com/EJF3rbD4

Answer (score 0):

Looks like PHP's mcrypt uses other CTR mode (big endian instead of little endian). Key schedule and IV are ok (as you can see on decrypting the first block), but something goes wrong in IV incrementing function.

See the following PHP code, which solves your problem by manually incrementing IV and encrypting gamma in ECB mode:

```
<?php
$encrypted = base64_decode('MlNFlnXE1sqIsmKZRtjChBvUMgiJlXgdjHVxQJ6JK24Id4uaN9NK/nBtY+cgrMJR/PRJRCmIUx0boQO5XqJYZ8VJ0w==');
$key = base64_decode('HB+dD1Irj2rXQ/nO+IuqSiK9xVE3PD9cZGIGzrMtwtA=');
$iv = base64_decode('2gxxKYU/G4lj7174e5wj+g==');

$ivarr = array_values(unpack('C*', $iv));
$ivdata = array_merge($ivarr);
$blocklen = count($ivarr);

for ($i = 1; $i < strlen($encrypted)/strlen($iv); $i++)
{
    // incrementing IV
    $ivarr[0] += 1;
    if ($ivarr[0] == 256)
    $ivarr[0] = 0;

    $j = 0;
    while ($ivarr[$j] == 0)
    {   
    $j++;
    if ($j == $blocklen)
        break;
    $ivarr[$j]++;
    }
    // appending to array
    var_dump($ivarr);
    $ivdata = array_merge($ivdata, $ivarr);
}

// now ivdata contains the full CTR gamma. Encrypting it.

$cryptor = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', '', 'ecb', '');
$res = mcrypt_generic_init($cryptor, $key, "");

$ivdatastr = implode(array_map("chr", $ivdata));
$ivdecr = mcrypt_generic($cryptor, $ivdatastr);

$ivdecr = array_values(unpack('C*', $ivdecr));
$decrypted = array_values(unpack('C*', $encrypted));
$i = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($decrypted); $i++)
{
    $decrypted[$i] = $decrypted[$i] ^ $ivdecr[$i % count($ivdecr)];
}    

$string = implode(array_map("chr", $decrypted));

var_dump($string);

mcrypt_generic_deinit($cryptor);
mcrypt_module_close($cryptor);
?>
```

Comment: Any pointers on how to use Little Endian?  Is there a PHP alternative to MCrypt that would do this?

Comment: It would be easier to change the iOS compatible code, but I don't know if you can change that.

Comment: At least you can manually increment IV for each block and use it. However, this would be slow. Easier would be to switch to CBC mode, or change endiannes on iOS side, as owlstead suggested.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the encryption on the iOS side is not an option.  But speed isn't so much a problem, since my PHP code will be doing it as a background process.  @NickolayOlshevsky -- Any pointers for how to implement IV incrementing in the manner that's needed?  I don't really understand endianness and CTR block incrementing.

Comment: See the updated answer. I don't know why I did it (coding byte-operations in PHP is a total pain), but it works.

Comment: Wow, getting close!  Thanks.  When I run it, I get a couple of issues though.  On line 33, `mcrypt_generic_init()` complains "Iv size incorrect; supplied length: 0, needed: 16".  Also, the final `var_dump()` shows the string has extra characters "\000" at the end.  How would you fix those?

Comment: Make sure that you are using correct 'ecb' mode. Or try to omit the IV parameter - ECB mode doesn't require IV. Does the length of input data is divisible by 16?

Comment: I ran your script as-is and got those errors.  The IV error went away if I used a string of 16 zero's for the IV instead of a blank string.  I'm still unsure about the other error.  The length of the plaintext can be any length, not necessarily divisible by 16.  I'm guessing I could use `trim()` on the output, but that's a messy hack.  The algorithm should be able to deal with this properly.

Comment: Oh yeah, there was another error too. No such index "0" in the final `for` loop.  If you want the bounty, I need a version of the algoritm that runs cleanly without all these errors.  Thanks!

Comment: You should add array_values since unpack returns 1-based array (why??). Again, script works fine in my conditions, and now that's your task to debug/adapt it to your conditions.